# ERROR: could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql-13/lib/age.so": /usr/local/pgsql-13/lib/age.so: undefined symbol: hash_any_extended

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I'm working with postgres 13 (REL_13_STABLE branch) from source code, and I'm using Apache AGE version 1.3.0 for that from (release/PG13/1.3.0 branch) from apachea/age source code which should be compatible with the version of postgres I'm using, but when I try to `CREATE EXTENSION age;` I get the following error:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION age;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql-13/lib/age.so": /usr/local/pgsql-13/lib/age.so: undefined symbol: hash_any_extended
```

though I checked `/usr/local/pgsql-13/lib/` and `age.so` turned to be stored there, therefore the error mostly for stating that I'm using incompatible versions of Postgresql and Apache AGE, even though I'm using branches supporting PG13 which should be compatible. So if this is the case what is the cause for the problem and how to solve?.

Comment: You built the extension against a different version of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that some other version of Apache AGE or Postgres still has files in your system. To ensure that Postgres 13 is being used, you can run the command `psql -c "SELECT version();"` in your terminal.

To address this issue, try running the following commands from your Apache AGE source code folder:

```
sudo make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config clean
sudo make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config
sudo make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config install
```

If the error persists after running the commands to clean and rebuild Apache AGE, you could consider uninstalling both PostgreSQL and Apache AGE and then reinstalling them with other compatible versions.

Note: you can use the branch `PG13` instead of `release/PG13/1.3.0` branch.

Comment: Thanks it worked, btw it's `make clean PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config` with configuration file path provided, thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Sorry about that, I forgot to include the file path in `make clean`. I'll edit and add it now so that everything is clear

Answer (score 1):

I believe your ApacheAge extension is not built correctly. Try rebuilding it and make sure to run regression tests after building the extension. Try running the below commands in your ApacheAge source directory:

```
make clean PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config 
make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config 
make install PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config  
make installcheck PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config
```

The above commands will do a clean install of your ApacheAge source code.

Answer (score 1):

The error `undefined symbol: hash_any_extended` suggests that the `age.so` library is built against a different version of PostgreSQL you are using. You can try to download the source code from the [official PostgreSQL directory](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/) and test different minor versions. There are minor versions of PostgreSQL from 13.0 to 13.11. Also, make sure you made a clean clone from the AGE repository to use with a different version of PostgreSQL. It prevents old files from older installations from polluting the new build.

Answer (score 1):

The following line means that you are using an incompatible version of the PostgreSQL:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql-13/lib/age.so": /usr/local/pgsql-13/lib/age.so: undefined symbol: hash_any_extended
```

Verify the compatible versions of PostgreSQL in the AGE Releases section github: [AGE RELEASES](https://github.com/apache/age/releases/tag/PG11%2Fv1.3.0-rc0)

You can install the compatible version of PostgreSQL by the following link:
[PostgreSQL Downloads](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/)

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to fix it is to unistall postgres using `make uninstall` and `make clean` and also deleting the files in the path `usr/local/pgsql-13`, then proceed to install postgres and the extension again and make sure the branches are the correct/compatible versions

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you might have different versions of PostgreSQL installed in your PC and the wrong version is being used when you try to create the **AGE** extension.

In your postgreSQL cli, type:

```
SELECT version();
```

to find your version of PostgreSQL. If the returned version is not PosgreSQL 13, change the path to point to bin of the correct version. Make sure you have separate directories for different versions of PostgreSQL installed.

Otherwise, if the correct version is returned, another possibility is that AGE wasn't built correctly. Refer to @wendel's answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

first clean all the previous installation by using

```
sudo make clean
```

now reinstall the postgres v13 from the github make sure to checkout pg13

```
https://github.com/postgres/postgres.git
```

then install age, set the env and run

```
sudo make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config clean
sudo make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config 
sudo make install PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config  install 
sudo make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config installcheck
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use the PG13 branch instead of the release/PG13/1.3.0 branch. I faced the same error when I used a newer version of age when I had installed and older version before.
You should reinstall postgreSQL 13 from source code. Then clone the git repository and move to the PG13 branch and install AGE from there using commands.

```
make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config install
make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config installcheck
```

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates that `age.so` library is built against a different version of PostgreSQL.
To resolve the issue, try these options:

- Make sure you are using the correct and compatible branches of Apache
  AGE and PostgreSQL.
- Clean your Apache AGE source code folder using this command:

  ```
  sudo make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config clean
  ```
- Run these commands to rebuild Apache AGE with the correct PostgreSQL
  version:

  ```
  sudo make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config
  sudo make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config install
  ```
- If the error still exists then try uninstalling both Apache AGE and
  PostgreSQL completely and reinstalling with compatible versions.
- You can check your PostgreSQL version using this command:

  ```
  psql -c "SELECT version();
  ```
- Also make sure you have clean clone of Apache AGE.